# how to fix error when load file with filename include charactor '%'

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am using URLRequest and URLLoader to load one text file with file name: "demo%.txt". This is my code

```
var urlFile:URLRequest      = new URLRequest(testFileOnLocal.nativePath);
var loaderFile:URLLoader    = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(testFileOnLocal.nativePath));
loaderFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadEditedTestComplete);
loaderFile.load(urlFile);
```

And it not work.
If I change file name to "demo.txt", it work. But '%' is allowed charactor of file name.
Can some one help me.
This is my error message:
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: file:///C:/Users/longpn4/Desktop/demo%.tmt

Comment: The % might be a valid character for files, yet it is a special character for URLs. Instead of **testFileOnLocal.nativePath** try, maybe **testFileOnLocal.url**.

Comment: yep, thanks so much bro. I have resolved it