# Using Actionscript Worker to loop function to make it faster

Tags: actionscript-3, air

My current code that allow application to upload data inside of Excel file into the AIR app is as follows;

```
import lib.xlsxreader.Worksheet;
import lib.xlsxreader.XLSXLoader;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var fileGet: File = new File();
    private var xloader: XLSXLoader = new XLSXLoader();

    public function Main()
    {
        fileGet = File.applicationDirectory;
        fileGet.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectExcel)
        xloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadComplete);
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectFile);
    }

    private function selectFile(e: MouseEvent): Void
    {
        fileGet.browseForOpen("Select File");
        xloader.load(fileGet.nativePath);
    }

    private function uploadComplete(e: Event): Void
    {
         ws = xloader.worksheet("[Name of the worksheet]");
         rowStart = 7;
         rowEnd = ws.rows;

         for (var i = rowStart; i <= rowEnd; i++)
         {
             //transferring data from excel into sqlite
         } 
    }
}
```

The code above is not my complete code, I just shorten it to the relevant code. Let me know if you need more information.

Right now the code is transferring data from 30 columns and 1000++ rows from Excel file for about 10 minutes which is kinda slow and make the AIR app appear 'hang' or 'frooze' during uploading.

It come to my attention that I can use Worker API in Actionscript to fasten this process but for the life of me, I can't exactly figuring out how to restructuring my code to allow Worker API in my code.

I have read through example from [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html#includeExamplesSummary), [here](https://github.com/probertson/as3-workers-examples) and [here](http://esdot.ca/site/2012/intro-to-as3-workers-hello-world), but I still can't make heads or tails on this issue.

As far as my understanding goes, my code `//transferring data from excel into sqlite` should be included in class CountResult from this [example](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html#includeExamplesSummary)...?

Can someone help me on this problem. Take note that I'm a self-learn amateur programmer trying to learn to make dekstop app using Adobe Animate.

Comment: The **Worker** thing is tricky. It's not like you can fork your application execution into two threads, like in Python. In AS3 you initialize the whole another AVM, basically, the second instance of Flash Player itself to execute a complete application. That **Worker** application must be aware it is running in the secondary thread so you need to set up some communication protocol between threads to issue commands and read status reports. On top of that, you cannot actually debug the **Worker** thread, because **trace** does not work there and there's no way to display things.

Comment: So base on my code, I can't properly use Worker for my case? I actually been meaning to analyse whether the reason behind the slow process is actually due from the excel reader, XLSXLoader class... if I can properly restructure my coding to use Worker API... where can I start?

Comment: **Worker** does not actually makes your application faster (it's the opposite, two Flash Players running at the same time, common sense), but it rather lets you decide WHERE your application is allowed to be slow. This way you can relieve your main thread (which also handles user input and display rendering) of any heavy, prolonged and continuous operations and put them into the **Worker** thread where it does not matter if they run 1 second, or 10, or 100. So, if I were at it, I'd start the **Worker** after I got the **File.url** (you'd better use this one rather than **File.nativePath**).

Comment: Why File.url instead of File.nativePath? doesn't nativePath can be used cross-platform while File.url refer to app:/ ? is this because of the white/blank space issue?

Comment: Well, this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096609/how-to-fix-error-when-load-file-with-filename-include-charactor Also, I previously had some issues with reading/writing files from **Worker** process then using **File.url** fixed these problems. You **might** not have any troubles using **File.nativePath**, just keep this in mind if you encounter any.