# Using Worker in AIR for Desktop doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, air, worker

Recently I make a Desktop App that allow user to import Excel data into SQLite. I make this app using AIR for Desktop. It come to my attention that my app will freeze when this import is in progress. So I thought that using Worker API in my Actionscript code will help to unfreeze my app while importing the data. This question is related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153868/using-actionscript-worker-to-loop-function-to-make-it-faster).

I read the [Worker API](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html), this [tutorial](http://esdot.ca/site/2012/intro-to-as3-workers-hello-world) and this [example](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2401) and I come up with following code;

MainClass.as

```
package
{
    // Import related class and API

    public class MainClass extends MovieClip
    {
        [Embed(source = "WorkerThread.swf", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
        private static var WORKER_SWF: Class;

        private var bgWorker: Worker;
        private var mainToWorker: MessageChannel;
        private var workerToMainProgress: MessageChannel;
        private var workerToMainResult: MessageChannel;
        private var workerToMainStartup: MessageChannel;

        public function MainClass()
        {
            initialize();
        }

        private function initialize(): void
        {
            // Setup the UI
            setupStage();
            createStatusText();
            createProgressBar();

            var workerBytes: ByteArray = new WORKER_SWF() as ByteArray;

            // Create the background worker
            bgWorker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(workerBytes);

            // Send to worker
            mainToWorker = Worker.current.createMessageChannel(bgWorker);
            bgWorker.setSharedProperty("mainToWorker", mainToWorker);

            // Receive progress from worker
            workerToMainProgress = bgWorker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);
            workerToMainProgress.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onWorkerToMainProgress)
            bgWorker.setSharedProperty("workerToMainProgress", workerToMainProgress);

            // Receive result from worker
            workerToMainResult = bgWorker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);
            workerToMainResult.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onWorkerToMainResult);
            bgWorker.setSharedProperty("workerToMainResult", workerToMainResult);

            // Receive startup message from worker
            workerToMainStartup = bgWorker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);
            workerToMainStartup.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onWorkerToMainStartup);
            bgWorker.setSharedProperty("workerToMainStartup", workerToMainStartup);

            bgWorker.start();

            setInterval(function ()
            {
                mainToWorker.send("ADD");
                trace("ADD", "main");
            }, 1000);
        }

        private function onWorkerToMainProgress(evt: Event): void
        {

        }

        private function onWorkerToMainResult(evt: Event): void
        {

        }

        private function onWorkerToMainStartup(evt: Event): void
        {
            var success: Boolean = workerToMainStartup.receive() as Boolean;

            if (!success)
            {
                //... handle worker startup failure case
            }
            else
            {
                trace("start");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WorkerClass.as

```
package
{
    // Import related class and API

    public class WorkerClass extends Sprite
    {
        private var mainToWorker: MessageChannel;
        private var workerToMainProgress: MessageChannel;
        private var workerToMainResult: MessageChannel;
        private var workerToMainStartup: MessageChannel;

        public function WorkerClass()
        {
            initialize();

        }

        private function initialize(): void
        {
            // Receive from main
            mainToWorker = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("mainToWorker");
            mainToWorker.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onMainToWorker);

            // Send to main
            workerToMainProgress = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("workerToMainProgress");
            workerToMainResult = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("workerToMainResult");
            workerToMainStartup = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("workerToMainStartup");
        }

        private function onMainToWorker(event: Event): void
        {
            if (mainToWorker.messageAvailable)
            {
                var msg: String = mainToWorker.receive() as String;

                if (msg == "ADD")
                {
                    trace("ADD", "worker")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I can see 'ADD, main' is been trace every few seconds but I don't see 'start' or 'ADD, worker' so I assume that my worker doesn't run even after I start it using `bgWorker.start();`. Does this have anything do to with `extend Sprite` since all of the tutorial and example are using it instead of `extend MovieClip` like in my MainClass.as

I have been working on this in my free time for almost a week and I still can't figure it out. My partner also been trying to figure this out with me.

Comment: As I mentioned on one of your previous posts, you cannot debug the **Worker** thread. That also means **trace** does not work from the secondary thread. Then, your **Worker** doesn't send anything, thus you won't be seeing '*start*' from the main thread as you are not triggering it in any way.

Comment: Oh yeah... I actually forgot you mention about that..  So how do I know if I setup it correctly? Is there a way to know? Is the reason in example esdot.ca to be able to trace in secondary thread is because all the code is in the same Document Class? If so, is that mean making all the Worker thread in a single class is better than doing it separately?

Comment: You indeed **can** write the whole code as a single application and fork its execution at **Worker.isPrimordeal** check. The upside: you can mock-debug the whole thing running both logics in one thread, and also it's easier to compose the code. The downside: if your application contain a lot of things, like raster graphics, assets, music, embedded fonts, etc, the **Worker** thread will be burdened with things it does not need.

Comment: In order to understand that your **Worker**... hm... works, you need to devise the 2-way communication so that main thread could read status reports from the **Worker** and **trace** them for you. You also need to think a lot about exception handling because if there's a runtime error in your **Worker** you'll never know unless you are prepared for it to happen.

Comment: _"...My app will freeze when this import is in progress."_ Is this using a big Excel file size? How many megs? Do you think it's the **reading** of input file or **writing** of database output that is slow?  It's not obvious how you're doing these things. Post a testable / example AS3 code that **recreates** your problem.